# React native iOS Library not loaded: @rpath/VuforiaEngine.framework/VuforiaEngine

Tags: ios, react-native, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have an issue when build react native iOS that have unity with Vuforia library in it. The project just crash after the build, and this is the error:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
0x105848798 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
0x10584879c <+4>:  svc    #0x80
0x1058487a0 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1058487c0               ; <+40>
0x1058487a4 <+12>: pacibsp 
0x1058487a8 <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
0x1058487ac <+20>: mov    x29, sp
0x1058487b0 <+24>: bl     0x10580a020               ; cerror_nocancel
0x1058487b4 <+28>: mov    sp, x29
0x1058487b8 <+32>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
0x1058487bc <+36>: retab  
0x1058487c0 <+40>: ret
```

and this is the log of the error:[image]

I already tested several solution but none of them works. Any suggestion or solution? Thanks!